# How to get a total count of records in dataframe B for each record on df A based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I have 2 df's that look like this

services_df

| Service id | Domain |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) |
| 222 | xyz.com |
| 333 | [www.opq.com](http://www.opq.com) |
| 444 | rst.com |

subscriptions_df

| Sub id | Domain | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | abc.com | Active |
| 22 | abc.com | Active |
| 33 | www.xyz.com | Cancelled |
| 44 | rst.com | suspended |

I need to add a new **total Active/Suspended Subs** column to df A that has the totals of active subs from df B for the corresponding domain, and I need to be as efficent as possible as the records on df A and df B are quite large (60-100K)

| Service id | Domain | Total Active/Suspended Subs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | abc.com | 2 |
| 222 | xyz.com | 0 |
| 333 | opq.com | #N/A |
| 444 | rst.com | 1 |

I came up with this function which works but is not very efficient

```
def numberOfActiveSubsTiedToDomainInServices(domain):
  #remove www and trim spaces
  domain = domain.replace('www.','').replace(' ','')
  #retrieve a count of active uber active services tied to the domain found in either domain or the domain in the service description
  try:
    return len(subscriptions_df.loc[(subscriptions_df['Domain'].astype(str).replace('www.','').replace(' ','') == domain) & (subscriptions_df['Status'].isin(['Active','Suspended']))])
  except:
    return '#N/A'

services_df['Total Active/Suspended Subs'] = services_df['Domain'].map(numberOfActiveSubsTiedToDomainInServices)
```

The problem I face with this approach is that is extremely time-consuming as it takes too long and I have to do similar counts on other columns.

is there a more pythonic way to do this that is more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
# first, make sure the domain names are the same in df1, df2
services_df["Domain"] = services_df["Domain"].str.removeprefix("www.")
subscriptions_df["Domain"] = subscriptions_df["Domain"].str.removeprefix("www.")

# make a crosstab from df2
tmp = pd.crosstab(subscriptions_df["Domain"], subscriptions_df["Status"])[
    ["Active", "suspended"]
].sum(axis=1)

# map the result from crosstab to df1
services_df["Total Active/Suspended Subs"] = services_df["Domain"].map(tmp)

print(services_df)
```

Prints:

```
   Service id   Domain  Total Active/Suspended Subs
0         111  abc.com                          2.0
1         222  xyz.com                          0.0
2         333  opq.com                          NaN
3         444  rst.com                          1.0
```